# Error "c does not name a type"

Tags: c++, class

So I tried searching and didn't find the problem I am having.

Here's mazesolve.cpp:

```
/*
   Mazesolve
   Reads a maze from stdin and outputs
   a solution to stdout
*/


#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "mazesolve_support.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
//Get maze header information
stringstream ss;
string line, header_maze, header_rows, header_cols;

getline(cin, line);
ss.clear();
ss << line;

for (unsigned int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    if (i ==0) {
        ss >> header_maze;
    } else if (i == 1) {
        ss >> header_rows;
    } else if (i == 2) {
        ss >> header_cols; 
    }

    if (ss.fail()) exit(1);
}

/*
cout << "header_maze = " << header_maze << "\n";
cout << "header_rows = " << header_rows << "\n";
cout << "header_cols = " << header_cols << "\n";
*/

return 0;
}
```

Here's mazesolve_support.cpp:

```
#include "mazesolve_support.h"
using namespace std;

cell::cell()
{

}

maze::maze(int rows, int cols)
{

}
```

And here's mazesolve_support.h:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class cell {
public:
    cell();
private:
    bool walls[4];
    int neighbors[4];
};

class maze {
public:
    maze(int,int);
private:
    vector<cell> cells;
};
```

I'm calling g++ with `g++ *.cpp -o mazesolve`.
The error I get is `error: c does not name a type` on line 4 of mazemake.cpp.

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error, as far as I know g++ should copy and paste mazesolve_support.h where my #include statement is, and therefore c would be declared. Any ideas?

Comment: classes are terminated with semi-colons

Comment: I had the semicolons, sorry I was kind of summarizing my code because it's a pain to copy/paste from vim through ssh.

Comment: The problem with your example is that the error may very well lie in the `...` areas.

Comment: Filled in the header file, the .cpp one is pretty much empty so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Could you show us the entire error message, or at least point out what line it occurs on?

Comment: I see one potential flaw... you're missing header guards.
If I add 'int main()' this compiles on my machine.

Comment: Your posted code is correct (other than the `....` lines and the lack of `main()`). Please post the actual code that you are having trouble with. It may be a pain for you to copy-paste, but it's even more of a pain for us to get our crystal balls out of storage

Comment: if you connect to your server with `ssh -X`, you can copy the whole text of the files from the remote shell with `xsel -i < file.c` or `xclip -i < file.c`, depending on what you have installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code compiles without problem with `g++ -c *.cpp -o mazesolve.o`.

Comment: Nevermind, looks like it was some problem on my end, maybe conflicting with another file, I don't know. It's compiling now. Thanks.